# "Could not start quickbooks" error using SDK on Windows 10

Tags: vba, quickbooks

We are running QuickBooks Enterprise 7 (I know it is old and not supported). I have MS Access applications that are using the SDK (via VBA)  to send transactions to QB. We have started upgrading computers to Windows 10. While QB works fine, the SDK is not. We are getting the error "Could not start QuickBooks". I need to get this fixed as it is a critical system. I have tried to upgrade the SDK to 13 but that didn't help either.

Comment: Hard to know anything without seeing some of the code you're using. It sounds like the Quickbooks data transaction isn't the problem so much as getting an instance of Quickbooks is. I'd look at wherever your code is opening the application and make sure everything looks kosher (most likely the path to Quickbooks changed in the upgrade and you're looking in the wrong place for it).

Comment: The path has not changed. Nothing has changed except the user's computer going to windows 10. Here is the code for the connection:
    Set QB = CreateObject("QBFC7.QBSessionManager")
    strDatabase = DLookup("Default_Company", "Configuration_table")
    'get the qb file information
    QB.OpenConnection2 "", "Upload Payroll", ctLocalQBD
    QB.BeginSession strDatabase, omMultiUser

Comment: And if you step through the code, I assume the error arises on the line `Set QB = CreateObject("QBFC7.QBSessionManager")`? It's likely that the upgrade modified namespaces or otherwise messed with your DLLs such that you can no longer create that object in that way.

Comment: Question: if you go into the VB Editor and try `Tools > References...` does "Quickbooks" show up in any of the libraries you can add? If so, we might be able to try manually referencing it and early binding...

Comment: It fails on the QB.BeginSession statement. Yes, there are libraries for QBFC items. Early binding does not seem to help..

Comment: If it's properly creating the object then that probably isn't the issue. One common problem people seem to be having is running the Quickbooks app and code at different user levels. Make sure if one is run as admin, so is the other.

Comment: I have already checked that. I made them both run as admin. I also tried setting (and the un-setting) compatibility mode, since they are both old applications. Nothing has made a difference yet.

Comment: Tried these: https://clearify.com/wiki/view/381/error-80040408-quickbooks-doesn-t-start?

Comment: I don't have QQube and the options shown don't exist in my old version for the other items.  Here is what is showing up in my log if it helps:
20160802.140046 I 7564 RequestProcessor Connection opened by app named 'Upload Payroll'
20160802.140051 E 7564 RequestProcessor An internal error occured while looking for a running instance of QuickBooks. Cannot continue. hr = 800401f3
20160802.140051 E 7564 RequestProcessor Could not create instance of QuickBooks. hr = 8004041c